# Python 2.7 Remove specific punctuations & stopwords

Tags: python, python-2.7, punctuation

I want to try 3 things in the code:

- Removing specific punctuations
- Converting input to lowercase
- Removing stopwords

How can I remove punctuations without using 'join.' function? I am new to Python and haven't succeeded removing the stopwords using the similar way yet...

```
import string
s = raw_input("Search: ")    #user input
stopWords = [ "a", "i", "it", "am", "at", "on", "in", "to", "too", "very", \
          "of", "from", "here", "even", "the", "but", "and", "is", "my", \
          "them", "then", "this", "that", "than", "though", "so", "are" ]

PunctuationToRemove = [".", ",", ":", ";", "!" ,"?", "&"]

while s != "":
    s1 = ""

#Deleting punctuations and applying lowercase
    for c in s:                             #for characters in user's input
        if c not in PunctuationToRemove + " ": #characters that don't include punctuations and blanks
            s1 = s + c                      #store the above result to s1
            s1 = string.lower(s)            #then change s1 to lowercase
    print s1
```

Comment: Why "without using join"? Is this homework, or do you just hold a grudge against join? How about regex? Also, your `while` loop never changes `s` and will thus run infinitely.

Comment: @tobias_k  it's just I want to manage the primary functions that I'm recently trying to absorb from here: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of all the stop words you could do:

```
[word for word in myString.split(" ") if word not in stopWords]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first getting rid of all punctuation. This can be done using a for loop:

```
for forbiddenChar in PunctuationToRemove:
    s = s.replace(forbiddenChar,"")        #Replace forbidden chars with empty string
```

Then, you can split the input string `s` into words, using `s.split(' ')`. Then, you can use a for loop to add all words, in lowercase, to a new string `s1`:

```
words = s.split(' ')
s1 = ""
for word in words:
    if word not in stopWords:
        s1 = s1 + string.lower(word) + " "

s1 = s1.rstrip(" ")         #Strip trailing space
```

Comment: You forgot to add spaces while constructing `s1`. And there you can also get rid of stopwords.

Comment: Hmm. Seems I wasn't paying attention. Edited to include what I intended to say :P

Comment: `s1 = s1 + " " + word.lower()`, I guess. Or `s1 = '%s %s' % (s1, word.lower()`

Comment: Seems I was right, I was indeed not paying attention. Though your suggestions would put a space at the start of s1, rather than at the end so I prefer putting it at the end (the trailing space can be stripped)

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
s = 'I am student! Hello world&.~*~'
PunctuationToRemove = [".", ",", ":", ";", "!" ,"?", "&"]
stopWords = set([ "a", "i", "it", "am", "at", "on", "in", "to", "too", "very", \
                "of", "from", "here", "even", "the", "but", "and", "is", "my", \
                "them", "then", "this", "that", "than", "though", "so", "are" ])

# Remove specific punctuations
s_removed_punctuations = s.translate(None, ''.join(PunctuationToRemove))

# Converte input to lowercase
s_lower = s_removed_punctuations.lower()

# Remove stop words
s_result = ' '.join(s for s in s_lower.split() if s not in stopWords).strip()

print(s_result)
#student hello world~*~
```

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension in `' '.join()`, you can use a generator expression instead (=> `' '.join(item for item in whatever)`). Also, you can simplify the expression `'' if s in stopWords else s for s in whatever` to `s for s in whatever if s not in stopWords`, which is more pythonic.